# json reading performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I am developping a client application with jquery+html5

I store my data in a file (70 MB)

data.json :

```
var myData = [
    {
      "id":"000000001",
      "title":"title1",
      "contents": [
               {"title":"title11", "description": "description", "text":"textextxxxxxxxx"}
               {"title":"title12", "description": "description", "text":"textextxxxxxxxx"}
               {"title":"title13", "description": "description", "text":"textextxxxxxxxx"}
      ]

    }
,.........
,.........
70Mb
]

//Application read this file and show "values" on console :
var data = myData
jQuery.each(data, function(){
           iterObject(this)
           })

iterObject : function(obj){
            var self = this
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                if((typeof value) == 'object'){
                    self.iterObject(value)
                }
                else {
                   console.log(value)
                }
            })
}
```

the problem is that it works very slowly

what is the best method to read a large object fastly?

thanks

Comment: Is this the same issue you asked about [previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399863/improve-program-performance)?

Comment: Do you need to read all the data at once?

Comment: 70meg? downloaded to a client? each page load? OUCH

Comment: Why in the world do you want to do that? What are servers for? Just because you learnt the word `JSON` does not mean you start using it for every problem.

Comment: Does the client need all 70mb of it at once? break it up into much smaller subsets of data.

Comment: yes. all data is needed at once

Comment: I find it impossible to even dream of the possibility that I might think of there existing a hypothetical parallel universe where a client _needs_ 70Mb's of data for a _page view_, let alone that being the best way of doing things... if you're using JSON, remember: AJAX is your friend...

Answer (score 2):

> what is the best method to read a large object fastly?

The best way is to split it. Right now your whole file needs to be loaded into memory, which is very resource consuming.

Instead, I see that your "object" is in fact a list, that could be split into chunks (eg. one JSON per line) and read one-by one, as the objects are needed.

In other words: split the load, do not load everything at once.

**EDIT**: I have just noticed you are loading it to the client. Please consider *caching* - do not load something that you already have, if that did not change in the meantime.

Comment: @Valeri: I cannot give you definite solution, because your question seems to contain invalid data (the actual content you have shown is not a content of valid JSON file). You can do it at least by storing one JSON per line, but you would still download the whole file. Instead you can additionally split these chunks into several files (whatever is suitable in your case) and read files one-by-one, then deserialize JSON-by-JSON.

Comment: Listen to Tadeck, the best way to do this client-side is by properly caching your info.